# Ninject property injection issue

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

Following on from my earlier question [on Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432096/understanding-ninject-with-a-more-complex-scenario)

I still cannot get property injection working..

The constructor parameter is injected but the property is not..
Am I doing this wrong??

```
    public class CokeConsumer
    {
    [Inject]
    public IDrinkCan Drink { get; set; }

    public CokeConsumer(IDrinkCan drink)
    {
        Drink = drink;
        Drink.OpenCan(330);
    }

    public void DrinkSomeCoke(int amount)
    {
        Drink.DrinkSome(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your Kernel bindings look like? How do you resolve `CokeConsumer`?

Comment: Thanks for posting back.. i think I solved my issue.. Its fairly obvious, but it seems ninject (not anythingelse i suspect) can set a property (BEFORE the object is created)!! doh! So I have to use "constructor injection" anyway. I have a follow up question but i havent finished investigating it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that silly..
you cant expect properties to be set before the object has been constructed!!